# recieving error The file you are attempting to save or retrieve has been blocked from this Web site by the server administrators.<nativehr>0x800401e6

Tags: web-services, sharepoint, deployment, wsdl, webexception

After building and deploying, checked the solution management from Central administration and it's up, a simple web service method that only created a Document Library list with a few columns when trying to retrieve the wsdl or even just by calling the WS fromt the adress since its a void method I recieve some error:

```
   The file you are attempting to save or retrieve has been blocked from this Web site by the server administrators.<nativehr>0x800401e6</nativehr><nativestack></nativestack>
```

The very same method runs fine when called from another web service project that is already deployed so there's nothing wrong with the code. I'm most probably doing something wrong but can't figure.
The system is running on a win server 2008 with sharepoint 2010, framework 3.5 and "ANY" cpu mode.
thank you!

[edit]
Managed to get rid of the previous error by removing asmx extention from the blocked file list in central administration now instead I'm recieving a 404 error:

```
  The resource cannot be found. 
  Description: HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.  Please review the following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly. 

  Requested URL: /_layouts1/my2claims/tt_claims.asmx
```

Answer (score 0):

it must run under the same application pool as SharePoint